# Prove that $A$ is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> **Problem:** Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ nonsingular matrix, and 
>   $$M = \begin{bmatrix}
>     A \quad B \\
>     C \quad D
> \end{bmatrix}  \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$$ 
>   with $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, $A \in \mathbb{K}^{k \times k}$, $D \in \mathbb{K}^{q \times q}$, $k<n$. Prove that $A$ is nonsingular.

**My attempt:** Since $M$ be a nonsingular matrix so every leading principal submatrices of $M$ nonsingular and $A$ be the leading pricipal submatrix of order $k$ of $M$. Q.E.D

Is that true? Thank all!

Comment: This would be true if $M$ is Hermitian and positive or negative definite.

Answer (score 4):

The claim in the problem is false: $M=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: You right! So how can I prove this problem?

Comment: @MinhNguyễnHoàng you cannot prove the statement in the problem as this answer shows that the claim in the problem is false.

Comment: In this case, $A$ could be the leading principal submatrix of $M$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $$M =\begin{pmatrix}  0& 0 & 0 &1 \\   0& 0 & 1 &2 \\   0& 1 &2  &1 \\  1 &2  & 3 &2  \end{pmatrix}$$ It's clear that $\det(M) = 1 \neq 0$, so $M$ is invertible. But $\begin{pmatrix}  0& 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the identity matrix $I=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ is nonsingular but it contains 1x1 submatrices (each of which with entry $0$) which are singular.

Comment: I meant the block matrix or principal submatrix $A$ with $M = \begin{bmatrix}
    A \quad B \\
    C \quad D
\end{bmatrix}  \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$.